# Html table row not appending to specified table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add the json string to an html table. The object data is correct but it is not appending to the table. What am I doing wrong with my jquery append statement?

```
    function GetSongs(id) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "Get",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetSongs", "Game")",
            data: { playlistId : id },
            success: function (data) {
                json = data;
                obj = JSON.parse(json);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#song-table').append('<tr>'+ htmlEncode(obj[i].SongURL) +'</tr>');
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

HTML Table:

```
               <div id="player-playlist">
                    <table id="song-table" style="width:420px">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Song</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>http://www.youtube.com/v/CFF0mV24WCY</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: What error you getting on?

Comment: HtmlEncode is not defined

Comment: you are also missing the `td` tags

Comment: if you want to use htmlEncode , then try to write custom function as shown in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `htmlEncode()`   because it is not defined in your js, define it or remove it

```
for (var i in obj) {
    $("#song-table").append("<tr><td>"+ obj[i].SongURL +"</td></tr>");
}
```

**OR**

```
for (var i in obj) {
    $("#song-table").append("<tr><td>"+ htmlEncode(obj[i].SongURL) +"</td></tr>");
}

function htmlEncode(string)
    {
        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        var text = document.createTextNode(string);
        pre.appendChild(text);
        return pre.innerHTML;
    }//end htmlEncode it escapes HTML
```

Answer (score 4):

First try to debug the output what data you getting on ,is it a JSON string you returning from server side, also try to append td inside tr, and for htmlEncode write the custom function htmlEncode as shown below

```
function GetSongs(id) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "Get",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetSongs", "Game")",
            data: { playlistId : id },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                json = data;
                obj = $.parseJSON(json);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#song-table').append('<tr><td>'+ htmlEncode(obj[i].SongURL) +'</td></tr>');
                }

            }
        });
    }

function htmlEncode (value) {
    if (value) {
        return jQuery('<div />').text(value).html();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Jquery is not defined

Comment: Use $.parseJSON(json)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append it to `<tr>` rather than `<td>`. Change it to:

```
$('#song-table').append('<tr><td>'+ htmlEncode(obj[i].SongURL) +'</td></tr>');
```